# Passing path to css file in JS function

Tags: javascript, css, export

I have found a function which creates a Word document from HTML. My goal is to embed CSS as a function argument. The function looks like this:

```
function exportWordDoc(nameOfFileToCreate, elementGetHTMLFrom) 
{
   var html, link, blob, url, css;

   // EU A4 use: size: 841.95pt 595.35pt;
   // US Letter use: size:11.0in 8.5in;
   css = (
     '<style>' +
     '@page WordSection1{size: 841.95pt 595.35pt;mso-page-orientation: landscape;}' +
     'div.WordSection1 {page: WordSection1;}' +
     'table{border-collapse:collapse;}td{border:1px gray solid;width:5em;padding:2px;}'+
     '</style>'
   );

   html =  $(elementGetHTMLFrom).html();
   blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', css + html], {
     type: 'application/msword'
   });
   url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
   link = document.createElement('A');
   link.href = url;
   // Set default file name. 
   // Word will append file extension - do not add an extension here.
   link.download = nameOfFileToCreate;   
   document.body.appendChild(link);
   if (navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob ) navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob( blob, nameOfFileToCreate + '.doc'); // IE10-11
        else link.click();  // other browsers
   document.body.removeChild(link);
 };
```

The function works so well. However, it is not versatile enough to use. I can choose a file name to element, and element obviously. My question - is it possible to specify css I want to use? To pass it as a function argument, but not in plain text(this is really big pain), but as external `.css` file let's say? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can add an element where you copy your HTML code to that you want in the doc and target the CSS according to the new container?